# Get id of current field using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I am working on a form and I need to write some jQuery that will get the current input field id.

In fact, when the user enters a value in the field, I need the code to automatically grab the id of this input field and store it in a variable. The problem is that I can not use the id to select it because that is the information I am after.

I have tried something like this:

```
Var test = $(this).attr('id');
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Wheres your code? You can use onchange, but you still need to bind that event some how. We don't know how you are generating the html, so it's hard to say how to do that.

Comment: can you post the entire click/submit code?

Answer (score 4):

A simple `this.id` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I still have an issue... Your code Ricardo works fine but as I'm using it in a Rails view with a nested_form (with a button to add and remove fields using Ryan Bates gem) elements that are added after the load of the page are not reacting to the code...

Answer (score 2):

First "Var" should be var

Second. You should be implementing this on the change event

```
var test;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(myinputfieldselector).change(function() {
    test = this.id;
  });
})
```

Finally.  I would be more specific but you would need to show your relevant code for this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your capitalisation was a typo, that should work, if you wrap it in a click event-handler:

```
$('input').click(
    function(){
        var test = $(this).attr('id');
        /* or, preferably to my mind, in plain JavaScript:
        var test = this.id;
        */
        console.log(test); // show the variable in the JavaScript console
        alert(test); // alerts the variable
    });
```

The reason I suggest wrapping this in the `click` event-handler, or any other for that matter, is simply to give context to the `this` (or the jQuery version of `this`: `$(this)`), from which the `id` can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code executing? Is it on submit of the form? When the text is entered into the field?

If you want to select all inputs from your form, you can write

```
inputElements = $("#idOfFormElement").find("input");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to put a class on the inputs that you desire to have this behavior. Here is an example:

```
<div id="choose-record-number">
    <input type="text" class="ip" id="number-records" value="50" />
    <input type="text" class="ip" id="record-type" />
    <input type="submit" class="ip" id="view-records" value="Visualizar" />
</div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Next, in jQuery, simply add a listener to the inserted class. This listener will be "activated" when any input is focused upon:

```
$(".ip").focus(
function() {
    $("#show").html($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Inside the function, accessing `$(this)` will get you the currently chosen input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I still have an issue... Your code Ricardo works fine but as I'm using it in a Rails view with a nested_form (with a button to add and remove fields using Ryan Bates gem) elements that are added after the load of the page are not reacting to the code...

Answer (score 0):

Hi everybody and thanks a lot for your help.

I've finaly found the way to do with this code that is a mix of all your inputs:

```
$("form").live("nested:fieldAdded", function() { //to listen to the new added line event
$('.ip').blur( //launching the function when the user enters something in the input field 
function(){
var test = this.id; //Get the id of the current field
var pattern = /[0-9]+/; //Only conserve the numeric part of it
var  intRegex = test.match(pattern);
var string = ('pinvoice_pinvlines_attributes_new_'+ intRegex +'_montant_HTVA'); //Build the string id
var a = document.getElementById(test).value //Get the value of the inputed field by the user
document.getElementById(string).value = a; //Finaly copy the value of the field in a new one using his specific id build with the STRING variable
});
});
```